# How to perform search and replace in lots of files with Emacs at once?

Tags: emacs, search, text-editing

I'm looking for a solution to how to perform a search and replace in all files in a directory using Emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution myself. [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) has builtin functionality to do that. See article *[Interactively Find and Replace String Patterns on Multiple Files](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html)* for further details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answer you'll want to use [dired](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html).

First mark the files via `m` key.  Alternatively you can use `% m` to `dired-mark-files-regexp` (in the case of marking all files, put `.*` as your regexp).

You'll want to use the `% R` to `dired-do-rename-regexp`.  This will limit the rename regular expression to the marked files.  You will have to use Emacs regexp syntax which differs from regular unix syntax.

If I had a number of files in a directory named the following:

```
 01.png
 02.png
 03.png
 04.png
```

And I wanted them renamed so they all were prefixed with chapter-01, I would input the following keystrokes.

```
% m - mark regexp
.*\.png - mark all png files
% R - rename regexp
\([0-9]+\)\(\.png\) - matching regexp, save the parens into variables
chapter-01-\1\2 - utilizing the previous variables`
! - during the query to denote rename all the rest
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's rather describing how to mass rename files than how to replace string in their content.